# MySQL - Problema em cláusula WHERE `coluna` != NULL [BUG?]

Tags: mysql

Me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Na minha aplicação tenho uma função que checa se *algum certo valor* já está em uso **em outro registro**, logo devo passar o `id` do registro atual para excluí-lo na *query* dessa função. E é aqui que acontece o problema. Se eu faço essa checagem **antes** de haver um registro, minha cláusula teria o `id != NULL`, que por minha lógica, deveria buscar esse tal valor em todos os registros, **já que eles têm, obrigatoriamente, um ID definido**!

Tudo explicado! Agora na prática:

```
SELECT VERSION();
-- +-------------------------+
-- | VERSION()               |
-- +-------------------------+
-- | 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 |
-- +-------------------------+

SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
-- +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
-- | @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                                                      |
-- +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
-- | STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
-- +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


CREATE DATABASE `teste`;

USE `teste`;

CREATE TABLE `tabteste` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `cpf` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `cpf` (`cpf`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


INSERT INTO `tabteste` (`id`, `nome`, `cpf`) VALUES
    (1, 'FULANO', '677.215.110-03'),
    (2, 'SICRANO', NULL),
    (3, 'BELTRANO', '612.463.660-37'),
    (4, 'FOO', NULL),
    (5, 'BAR', '755.926.990-77'),
    (6, 'FUBÁ', '577.862.570-71');

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `quant` FROM `tabteste` WHERE (`cpf` = '577.862.570-71' AND `id` != 6);
-- RETORNA 0, POIS O ID 6 (FUBÁ), PASSADO COMO PARÂMETRO NA QUERY, USA ESSE CPF
-- +-------+
-- | quant |
-- +-------+
-- |     0 |
-- +-------+

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `quant` FROM `tabteste` WHERE (`cpf` = '577.862.570-71' AND `id` != 1234);
-- RETORNA 1, POIS O ID 6 (FUBÁ), DIFERENTE DO PARÂMETRO 1234 NA QUERY, JÁ ESTÁ USANDO ESSE CPF
-- +-------+
-- | quant |
-- +-------+
-- |     1 |
-- +-------+

SELECT COUNT(*) AS `quant` FROM `tabteste` WHERE (`cpf` = '577.862.570-71' AND `id` != NULL);
-- RETORNA 0 POR QUÊ? CONSIDERANDO QUE O ID 6 É DIFERENTE DE NULL!
-- +-------+
-- | quant |
-- +-------+
-- |     0 |
-- +-------+
```

Na última *query SELECT* deveria retornar `1` também, já que `6` é diferente de `NULL` !

**Por que isso acontece?**

Quero resolver isso sem ter de criar uma condição dentro da aplicação pra checar se o `id` é `NULL` e escrever uma *query* só pra isso, visto que **aparentemente** isso seria um *BUG* do *MySQL*.

Comment: `Null` não é valor, é um estado, ou seja o seu campo esta nulo. Para isso você uso o `IS NULL` ou o `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `NULL` é uma figura criada para representar um valor **não definido** ou **não conhecido**, portanto não pode ser comparado a nada (nem comparado com nulo mesmo). Ou ele é nulo, ou não.

Entendendo de outra forma, não temos como saber se isso é verdade:

```
valor desconhecido = valor desconhecido
```

Nem isso:

```
valor desconhecido <> valor desconhecido
```

pois eles poderiam teoricamente ser ou não iguais.

Para saber se um campo é nulo ou não, se usam `IS NULL` e `IS NOT NULL`.

Corrigindo sua *query*:

```
... WHERE (`cpf` = '577.862.570-71' AND `id` IS NOT NULL)
                                           --^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Acontece que não quero saber se o campo é nulo ou não. Na função, esse valo é passado como parâmetro, mas se o usuário não definir esse valor, a query não funcionaria. A minha intenção era não reescrever a função condicionando o valor do parâmetro pra depois definir a query. Mas em fim, vou ter que fazer isso mesmo. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Então é um [Problema XY](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499). Você perguntou partindo de uma solução inadequada, em vez de expor o problema real na pergunta. Neste caso a solução é quando o parâmetro for vazio, omitir o AND todo.

Comment: *"Na minha aplicação tenho uma função que checa se algum certo valor já está em uso em outro registro, logo devo passar o id do registro atual para excluí-lo na query dessa função."* Talvez não tenha ficado claro suficiente. Vou me empenhar mais na próxima pergunta!

Comment: @LipESprY quanto mais você focar no problema real (preferencialmente com o código em questão da parte com o problema), mais fácil de ajudarmos mais diretamente com o que você precisa. Por exemplo, se tivesse o código em questão, grande chance da resposta ter proposto algo como `if( !empty( $parametro ) ) $query .= " AND id = $parametro";` (se fosse PHP, por exemplo)

Comment: Tranquilo. Eu só não queria mexer no lado da aplicação. Achei que existisse algo pra "habilitar" isso no MySQL, visto que no PHP, por exemplo, é possível fazer comparações com `null`. Mas o problema em si já foi resolvido. Obrigado.